# Devise SessionsController#create: Override default sign-in strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here's my problem:

I currently have two routes allowing users to sign-in:

- an admin route: `host/admin/sign_in` for users with the `admin` role
- a "normal" route: `host/users/sign_in` for users without the `admin` role

I'd like to restrict the sign-in strategy based on the combo route/user role:

- an `admin` can't sign-in through the normal route `host/users/sign_in`
- a normal user can't sign-in through the admin route `host/admin/sign_in`

### What I've tried

- I've generated Devise's `SessionsController` and overwritten the `#create` method.
- I've added a condition that specifies if the authentication process should follow along with the base strategy, or if it should do some custom stuff.

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    if !resource.admin?
      # Normal authentication strategy
      sign_in(:user, resource)
      yield resource if block_given?
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    else
      # custom strategy
      flash[:info] = t('not_authorized')
      respond_with resource, location: root_path
    end
  end
end
```

At this point, when an `admin` tries to log-in through the "normal" route, they see a flash with the error, they are redirected to the root **but they are logged in anyway**.

After checking issues on Devise's GitHub, it would seem that the `prepend_before_action :allow_params_authentication!` in the `SessionsController` is causing the authentication strategy to run again. [See known issue here](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5013#issuecomment-459305096). The issue is closed with [this commit](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/commit/4be9389dcb791b063825b4996df8d04cbf7e0e89). But this won't be released until version 5 of Devise.

What I've done so far is to add a `sign_out` before my alert + redirection.

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    if !resource.admin?
      # Normal authentication strategy
      sign_in(:user, resource)
      yield resource if block_given?
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    else
      # custom strategy
      sign_out
      flash[:info] = t('not_authorized')
      respond_with resource, location: root_path
    end
  end
end
```

This works okay. But I'm unhappy with the fact that an `admin` has to be signed in and signed out on the fly. It also messes up with the `sign_in_count` of my users.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? And how did you manage to work around it?

Comment: you should look into how to define devise/warden custom authentication strategies. this you don't have to override the sessions controller. example: https://insights.kyan.com/devise-authentication-strategies-a1a6b4e2b891

Comment: Thank you for this resource! This seems like the cleanest way to do it. I'll report back.